# local variable 'user' referenced before assignment but I assigned user.id

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have created a **function** to set a boelian to false :

```
def verification(request, user_id):
#get currently logged in user
user = request.user
user = user.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user.profile.first_visit = False
user = user.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user.save()
return redirect('create-workspace')
```

I added this to my **template**

```
{% url 'firstvisit' user.id %}
```

And this to my **path**

```
path('first_visit/<user_id>', views.verification, name="firstvisit")
```

My models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
group = models.OneToOneField(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So everything looks in order, but it says user is not assign...

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: 'UnboundLocalError at /users/first_visit/1
local variable 'user' referenced before assignment'

 - Yes but I have imported from the "django.contrib.auth.models"

Comment: @Carcigenicate If used for example 'user = request.user' it says 
**Manager isn't accessible via User instances**

Comment: I have added my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you're trying to achieve and I think your issue might be that you are querying the wrong table for what you want:

```
def verification(request, user_id):
#get currently logged in user
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
user_profile.first_visit = False
user_profile.save()
return redirect('create-workspace')
```